# pjax - render page on error

Tags: jquery, pjax

I'm using pjax and I'd like to configure it to render the page (replace the html) as if everything is normal, even though the page responds with a non-200 code (404, 500).

My 404 and 500 pages are tweaked to look nice, and I don't need pjax to refresh the page.

I couldn't figure out how to do this from all the documentation I've read, including the [original git repo](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should consider choosing the answer @fyrite provided as correct. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the success function from the pjax:error handler, and return false to prevent the automatic hard refresh:

```
$(document).on('pjax:error', function(event, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, options) {
    options.success(xhr.responseText, textStatus, xhr);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I have actually been dealing with the same issue - it's a weird quirk of jQuery PJAX that when you hit a 404/500 page, it seems to perform the request as you would expect (i.e. retrieve the contents of your 404 page), but instead of doing the usual replace it does a hard reload.

The `pjax:error` event that is fired when you hit a 404/500 page is actually what causes the hard refresh, much like `pjax:timeout` does. What you can do is prevent the hard refresh by using something similar to the following:

```
$( document ).on('pjax:error', function( event, request ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, if you inspect the contents of the `request` object in the above, you'll see that PJAX was in fact successful in retrieving the contents of the 404 page, available in `responseText`. At this point I suppose you could use jQuery to replace the entire contents of your PJAX container with the contents of `responseText`, however I suspect this would break pushState.

I'm still working on getting it all working correctly, but I hope this helps since there is very little documentation on this!

Comment: I actually started writing that, but didn't inspect `request` variable (the example I found didn't receive it). Would be nice if it were simply a flag `continue_on_error=true`